# UrlFetchApp Service Time Out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

the urlfetch has a limited data allowed so in order to load a large CSV or TSV file (50K) I've created a proxy server (REST)
which makes the request under the hood, map it to list and cache it for 6 hours. 
then, I added an endpoint to fetch data based on a range (see signature below)

signature:
var PROXY = 'http://lagoja-services.rcb.co.il/api/adwordsProxy/feed/{base64URL}/{seperator}/{from}/{to}'

when someone reaches the range endpoint, I create a CSV on-the-fly.
the first loading of this large file on the server takes between 60-80 seconds, other followed requests take the content from the cache so it takes only 2 seconds.

the problem I have is that I'm getting a timeout after 60 seconds using the urlfetch  built-in class so it Alternately works (sometimes it works and sometimes getting  timeout exception)
there is no way of reducing the first load!

it seems that I can't control the client timeout (from some unknown reason)

any other solution for me?

thanks, Roby (-:

---

hi, I've created a dedicated "test" endpoint for you to reproduce the issue. this endpoint tries to load the massive file every time (no cache)

```
function main() {  
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://lagoja-services.rcb.co.il/api/adwordsProxy/test');
   var status_code = response.getResponseCode();
   Logger.log('status code %s', status_code);
}
```

endpoint:
http://lagoja-services.rcb.co.il/api/adwordsProxy/test

exception:
Timeout: http://lagoja-services.rcb.co.il/api/adwordsProxy/test

---

hi all, 
i found a solution (which i don't like of course)
but i didn't have any better suggestion.

the idea is to ping the server to fetch the file, wait till it loaded into the cache and then request the loaded content... a shitty solution but at least it works lol

api:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/fire")]
        public HttpResponseMessage FireGetCSVFeed(...) {

            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct => {
                // make a request to the original CSV file - takes 60-80 seconds
            });

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Working...");
        }
```

adwords script:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + milliseconds);
}

function main() {  
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL + 'fire');

sleep(1000 * 120); // yes i know, i'm blocking everything )-: 

response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL + 'getCSV');
  status_code = response.getResponseCode();   
  Logger.log('status code %s', status_code);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? How do you run the script including `UrlFetchApp`?

Comment: If I got it right, during the first request the CSV file is generated - which takes (60-80 sec), while during the following requests the generated content is retrieved, which only takes 2 sec? In this case, you might  try to implement a try...catch statement.  Request to fetch the response within the try block, and if it fails, request it again within the catch block. Provided that the generated file will be saved in your cache after you request the generation within `try`, you should be able to retrieve its contents within `catch` without running into time out issues.

Comment: It would be easier if you could split the massive file in several smaller ones, fetch them separately and then join again once they are on your Google Drive.

Comment: hi  ziganotschka, thanks for your reply...   
some more information about the case: 
i've created an adwords script, which based on a client CSV (which lives in his domain) and manages a fully functioning campaign. i've noticed that the UrlFetchApp has a limit of load response size and it truncates the response if it reaches that limit. to solve this issue, i had to find a solution of reading all rows within the original CSV so i've created a proxy server to read it by bulks and then i use the UrlFetchApp to make X requests and assemble it to a single file.

Comment: the way i implemented the proxy is by reading the full CSV on the server, convert it into a model and store it into the cache... then, a client request a bulk instead of ALL rows at once (you'll see something like 'api/feed/1/1000', 'api/feed/1000/2000' etc.)... 
the first execution (on the server) takes 60-80 seconds and resulted in timeout

Comment: hi Tanaike, i added a code sample to the ticket
to run it, go to your adwords account > scripts > add > paste my sample and run

Comment: @Rc B: Your approach of reading by bulks and perform multiple UrlFetchApp requests sounds promising. What you need to do is to make the bulks smaller (and thus faster to retrieve) in order to avoid the timeout.

Comment: yes, this approach was tested and works as long as I'm NOT using the UrlFetchApp for the first request (the one which saves it to the cache). 
to read all the stream of this file (apprx. 80mb) on the server takes an avg time of 70 sec. the client (UrlFetchApp) breaks the connection after 60 so the request terminates and doesn't complete the stream. in this case, next call will be referred as the first call (there's no cache). 
that's the reason i need to increase the timeout to at least 2 minutes but i can't find a way of controlling it when using the UrlFetchApp service

Comment: I don't think you can, you need to reduce the file size instead.